# Cannot use POCO Timer in NPAPI plugin

Tags: c++, npapi, poco-libraries

I have implemented an NPAPI plugin which works in Firefox. Next, I tried adding a method which accepts a function from the JavaScript side as a callback.

Initially I tried to call this callback method immediately in the same method, which did exactly nothing on the JavaScript side.

I then tried to implement a timer using Poco::Util::Timer and TimerTask. When trying to instantiate a Timer or TimerTask in any fashion in the code, Firefox will no longer load the plugin. In about:plugins there is no trace of the plugin.

To my knowledge there is no way to figure out why a plugin doesn't get loaded, nor have I found any references on what is and isn't allowed when implementing an NPAPI plugin.

Any pointers will be most helpful. I can post code if required.

Comment: Just to verify, are you aware that support for NPAPI will be removed from Firefox with the release next month?

Comment: Yes, the sole reason why I picked NPAPI is because I looked at PPAPI first and it cannot do the one thing which I need, which is to directly call methods and read properties in a plugin. As this is for a commercial project (testing & validating JavaScript apps running on a proprietary platform using NPAPI-based plugins), we have little choice.

Comment: PPAPI also can't be used without special command line flags to enable your plugin... it's not in any way a replacement for NPAPI.

Comment: Yup, the registering is still okay for this project, but not being able to register one's own API methods is a total deal-breaker.

Comment: With PPAPI it's not a question of registering, it's a question of "it doesn't actually work the way you probably think it works". There are only a couple of plugins which are supported directly via PPAPI and others have to use PPAPI via nacl.  I think the direct ones actually do support API methods, but you can't just register those you have to pass in special flags each time you run the binary in order to enable them.  Also I'm not sure you'll find the docs for it.

Comment: Yes, that's pretty much what I gathered after a few days of research. Quite a shame, as it makes PPAPI much less useful than NPAPI. Likely these special API methods change every few Chrome releases as well, making them even less useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main thing you need to understand about a NPAPI plugin is that you can't interact with the browser *in any way* from an alternate thread.

I'd go back to your first test first, though, because calling the NPObject passed in (using InvokeDefault) should have worked if you do it immediately.

My guess is that with your timers you're probably either running on a different thread or you're trying to usurp the message loop in the plugin thread, both of which will cause you issues.  Have you looked at FireBreath? FireBreath 1 would probably give you everything you need without needing to know all the implementation details of NPAPI.

Comment: I looked at Firebreath, but wasn't sure the project is maintained any more. You're probably right about Poco Timer not playing nice with the plugin message loop. I'll give the original code (immediately invoking default method) another try, but I find plugins to be extraordinarily hard to debug.

Comment: Maintained is a relative term.  There isn't a lot of active development because nobody seems to feel the need to contribute and there aren't any major bugs, but the author (me) is still around.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I went back to directly calling the callback in the method which receives it, and found that the reason why it didn't seem to work before was due to a JavaScript error (a JSON.stringify() instance embedded in another one).

Comment: I'll take a look at FireBreath as well to see what it can do for me. As far as NPAPI browser support, maybe Pale Moon might be a FireFox alternative going forward. What do you think? :)